# Query runs in the same time despite having 300 times as many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have two (almost) identical queries:

```
;with cteMasterCreateExecAsXml as (
    SELECT guid, CAST(ExecutionOrder AS xml) as x
    FROM (SELECT guid, ExecutionOrder 
          FROM @StrategiesToCreate sc
          JOIN InFusion_Data.dbo.compare_FoxStrategy fs ON fs.Guid = sc.MasterGuid
          WHERE fs.LinkedToTemplate = 0) k
) -- selects ~45 rows

SELECT MasterBIV.StrategyTagname, MasterBIV.Tagname, MasterBIV.Name,
       b.blk.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as ExecOrder
       INTO #MasterCreateExecOrder
FROM cteMasterCreateExecAsXml
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('//ExecutionOrder/Block') as b(blk)
JOIN InFusion_Data.dbo.compare_BlockInfoView MasterBIV ON MasterBIV.BlockGuid = b.blk.value('@Id', 'uniqueidentifier')
```

And

```
;with cteMasterExecAsXml as (
    SELECT guid, CAST(ExecutionOrder AS xml) as x
    FROM (SELECT guid, ExecutionOrder FROM @StrategiesToCompare sc
    JOIN InFusion_Data.dbo.compare_FoxStrategy fs ON fs.Guid = sc.MasterGuid) k
) -- selects ~17000 rows

SELECT MasterBIV.StrategyTagname, MasterBIV.Tagname, MasterBIV.Name,
       b.blk.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as ExecOrder
       INTO #MasterExecOrder
FROM cteMasterExecAsXml
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('//ExecutionOrder/Block') as b(blk)
JOIN InFusion_Data.dbo.compare_BlockInfoView MasterBIV ON MasterBIV.BlockGuid = b.blk.value('@Id', 'uniqueidentifier')
```

According the SQL execution plan they both take the same amount of time. The first one deals with 45 rows and the second one deals with ~17000 rows. This makes me think that many rows are being selected and converted to xml in both queries.

Unfortunately because I need to do the query across servers I can't use an XML column in the schema.

Any idea what's going on here or how I can speed up my queries?

Comment: Execution plans usually don't show timings =P You might mean COST?  Yes there is a link but no it's not quite the same thing. You need to run and time each query separately or use something like SQL Plan Explorer to get a view on how something runs and even then you only get timings for the entire query, not for each 'part' that makes up the entire operation. Also, @table-variables are notoriously bad when there is a lot of data (17k rows is a lot in this context). Rather use #temp-tables as these have proper statistics handling and also allow for indexing. The optimizer will be grateful =)

Comment: Using temp tables made a huuuuge difference! The query is nice a quick now. Also running it as a stored procedure helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, the diffence is at  "WHERE fs.LinkedToTemplate = 0" condition.

> According the SQL execution plan they both take the same amount of time. The first one deals with 45 rows and the second one deals with ~17000 rows.  This makes me think that many rows are being selected and converted to xml in both queries.

It looks like you have no table index by *LinkedToTemplate* column, so for both queries [full table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) is needed.
So to improve performance you should create index by *LinkedToTemplate* column.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens I was using the wrong index - I had a pk set up on StrategyName and should have been joining using that instead of guid. I'm still not entirely sure what's going on with the execution plan though, I think it's not totally accurate in this case - it's not a slow query and if I take it out of the batch the batch still runs in almost the same time.